# How to clean up a noisy 3d point cloud?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running ros melodic rtabmap rgbd_odometry. I'm getting a noisy point cloud, which I tried to filter by using the rtabmap_ros parameters:

cloud_noise_filtering_radius, cloud_noise_filtering_min_neighbors

which map to rtabmap parameters

/rtabmap/Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius, /rtabmap/Grid/NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors

I can see that the parameters are passed into the rtabmap process:

```
ps1 ros | grep -i rtabmap
opt/ros/melodic/lib/rtabmap_ros/rtabmap --udebug --Grid/NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors 80000 --Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius 90000.0 rgb/image:=/camera/rgb/image_color depth/image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw rgb/camera_info:=/camera/rgb/camera_info rgbd_image:=rgbd_image_relay left/image_rect:=/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color right/image_rect:=/stereo_camera/right/image_rect left/camera_info:=/stereo_camera/left/camera_info right/camera_info:=/stereo_camera/right/camera_info scan:=/scan scan_cloud:=/scan_cloud user_data:=/user_data user_data_async:=/user_data_async odom:=odom __name:=rtabmap
```

I set the parameters to very big values (**NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors 80000 NoiseFilteringRadius 90000.0**), for sanity check.

I expect that the rviz will filter all the 3d points and that the point cloud will be empty, but I'm getting the same point cloud as when cloud_noise_filtering is disabled (NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors 2 NoiseFilteringRadius 0)

```
rosparam get /rtabmap/Grid/NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors 
'2'

rosparam get /rtabmap/Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius 
'0'
```

NoiseFilteringRadius_0__NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors_2
What should I do so that the cloud_noise_filtering takes effect?

Thanks,
Avner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314051/how-to-clean-up-a-noisy-3d-point-cloud?/) by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-01-28**:
Which topic are you visualizing in RVIZ? Those parameters only affect `/rtabmap/cloud_map` output.

**Comment by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on 2019-01-28**:
ok. so I'm now looking at /rtabmap/cloud_map. I set: the Radius to 0.1 and MinNeighbors to 80000
My understanding id is that there must be 80000 in a radius of 0.1 (what units ?)
Since the NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors number is big, I expect that all the points will be filtered but I still see points

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-01-29**:
units are in meters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After removing the map rtabmap.db
and starting fresh with extreme numbers:

NoiseFilteringRadius to 0.1, and NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors to 80000

I'm now not seeing 3d points in /rtabmap/cloud_map as expected.

Thanks for your help.

Avner

---

Originally posted by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) with karma: 96 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0